# Compute the maximum distance from any node currently on the path to the specified node?

Tags: java, list

Here, I tried this, but has bugs somewhere and I am trying to fix it.

```
private int maxDistance(List<String> path, String node) {

  int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
  int cost = 0;


  for ( int i = 0 ; i < path.size(); i++)
  {
      path.add(i, node);

      if ( cost > max)
          cost = max;

      path.remove(i);
  }
  return max;
```

Comment: `has bugs somewhere` is not helpful. *What* and *where* are they?

Comment: I could not figure that out, but not giving the right result ! That's where I need help, I guess.

Comment: For the moment I can only say that "int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; " is strange because "cost > max" will never be true But you gave not enough information about your bug

Comment: what is in `node`? What is the format of it's value? What defines the cost?

Comment: node is the String type ; Its value type is cost; and cost is the distance between two nodes; its the edge value from the graph.

Comment: give me an example of node. Is it just an integer? What does your function call look like?

Comment: No, Node is a String lets Say we have graph connected to different airport, Node is the Airport name. Path is the List of airports on the rote traveled.

Comment: String look like " Hello " . In my case. It contains airport names "LAX", " SFO", " JFK ". Sorry, its hard for me to make u understand.

Comment: So we want to find `node` in `path`? What are we doing with it?

Comment: so, I need to find a node in a longest distance from the path ( Path is the List of nodes ) and add that to path if it is not aready in a path.

Comment: What is the distance? An arbitrary number? Or are you getting that from somewhere/have it stored somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't changing `cost` to mean anything, and `max` is already the maximum possible value, so your code doesn't really do anything:

```
private int maxDistance(List<String> path, String node) {
  int max = 0, cost = 0; // Checking for a max

  path.add(node); // You only want to do this once, so do it outside the loop

  for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    // find the cost somehow, you didn't specify what 'cost' really is
    if(cost > max)
      max = cost;
  }

  return max;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, Finally was able to explain you what i was trying to do, n u helped me.